# ClassNotFoundException with Spring WebFlux Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm having the following problem:

I am trying to setup a basic Spring Boot (2.0.0.M2) Project containing Spring Webflux and Spring Security.

My pom.xml looks like this (generated via start.spring.io):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

SpringSecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebFluxSecurityConfiguration {}
```

I am not getting any further because I get an exception on startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextRepository
```

So I figure that the whole `org.springframework.security.web.server` package is not on the classpath, although it should be there, since it is included in the [API docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/5.0.0.M2/api/).

Seems like I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: You have to add the dependency. Afaik the security flux jar isn't part of the `spring-boot-starter-security` stuff. If it is try purging your local repository and re download the dependencies.

Comment: You're right, it's not part of it. I was expecting it to be because it is included in the Spring Security 5.0.0.M2 API-docs. Thanks!

Comment: could you answer to your own question then? This should help other developers in the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Spring Boot's `spring-boot-starter-security` does not include `spring-security-webflux`.

Add it as project dependency explicitly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

See this [issue : Provide auto-configuration for WebFlux-based security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9925).

BTW, check my working codes: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/boot

**Updated**: In Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE, `spring-boot-starter-security` includes webflux support.